# Digital Signature for project

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, code-signing, certificate-signing-request

i want to know for me to sign digitally software(i am not a developer just an investor)

Do i need to use services like comodo or it can be done manually, for example i freelance soft like desktop app for speed up pc. Now i need to sign it with EV certificate right?

I do need this for:

1. Windows Defender acting normally with my soft
2. Browsers does not notifying about suspicious website

Am i correct or it is not true?

And if i need it, can i do it manually some how or need to do via comodo like services?

Comment: One typically would just purchase the appropriate code signing certificate and use it during compilation using Visual Studio or similar tool

Comment: so it is not possible to do it by yourself?

Comment: Do what exactly? Can you clarify your question by editing it? If you want your executable to be trusted you have to use a valid code signing certificate. Now you can trust any certificate, but if you want no additional steps, like installing the certificate then best use a Root CA that’s already trusted by default. How does the developer want to handle this situation?

Comment: thanks i get it, thank you